# Problem to read rows of data in excel faster

Tags: c#, excel

I would like to read data and plot a XY graph. I have 2000 rows of data with only 2 columns. I'm reading from Row1Column1 to Row1Column2 for now but it's reading quite slow. Is there any faster way to read it?

I tried using global variable to replace `int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;` and also set `int colCount = 2` since my column number is fixed to only two. But then i got an error saying that **Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference, But it is NOT a null reference**.

```c
Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet1.UsedRange;

            int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
            int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

            for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString());
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, j] = xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString(); //This line throws the error
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

            Excel.Range chartRange;
            Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
            Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(200, 80, 300, 250);
            Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;

            chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlXYScatter;
```

Comment: What line of code in the posted code throws the error... _"Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference"_

Comment: Excel Interop is very slot because commands get converted to a scripting language.  Use Oledb with either the Jet or Ace driver.  See : https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

Comment: @JohnG xlWorkSheet.Cells[i,j] = xlRange.Cells[i,j].Value2.ToString(); this line throws the error

Comment: @ThanishK Excel Interop is *slow*, and what you do makes it a lot slower - each property or cell call is a cross-pocess call to Excel, which is hundreds of times slower than a method or property calle. By accessing N cells one by one, you make things N times slower. You should use range-based operations at least

Comment: @ThanishK even better, DON'T use interop to create Excel sheets. Use a library like Epplus to create the Excel sheet in your own application. Excel files are ZIP packages containing XML documents, so there's no need to use Excel itself. In may cases, like web servers, you simply can't use Excel anyway

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Hmm what changes do i have to make to my code? I couldnt think of any better ways to access the data faster. I will look into the library in my next project cause i'm almost done with this..

Answer (score 0):

As already commented, using Excel Interop is notoriously slow. There are often ways around this, like now. However, there are other advantages to using a third-party library. Namely, when using Interop, the target computer must have the same Excel library as the one the code uses.

Also, I am aware that you may have no choice. It is not unusual for a company to disallow using any third-party libraries. So, your hands may be tied.

If you have to use Interop, then as commented already, doing this copy cell by cell is going to be slow. A better approach is to use Excel's `Range.Copy` command. In my tests, this reduced the time significantly.

If I am not mistaken you state that it was just the first two columns you needed copied, and if there are more columns, then it should not be difficult to alter the code to what you need.

Therefore, the code below will copy the first two columns from the source worksheet to the destination worksheet. It took less than two (2) seconds with a sheet of 2200+ rows.

```
string cell1 = "A1";
string cell2 = "B" + rowCount.ToString();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range sourceRange = xlWorkSheet.Range[cell1, cell2];
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range destinationRange = xlWorkSheet2.Range[cell1, cell2];
sourceRange.Copy(destinationRange);
```

Lastly, I am confident the reason you are getting a `null` exception is that one or more of the cells in the source worksheet are `null` and when the code tries to call the `ToString` method with a null value… well you know what happens.

Add a check for this `null` value before you call its `ToString` method. Something like…

```
if (xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null) {
  xlWorkSheet2.Cells[i, j] = xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString();
}
```